# Signing up a new Firebase account using a currently logged acount(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an educational app wherein teachers can create/edit/delete topics and activities for the students while monitoring their progress(like SoloLearn), i'm at 90% progress now and was testing the app when I encountered this problem. I create the app so that only the teacher accounts can create accounts for the students. As I login the teacher account it will show the basic info of the teacher(name, email, advisory class), seems good, but when I created an account for a student(teacher account currentUser), my app replaces the currentUser with the student account that I just created(Tested).

So my question is how can I resolve the issue where in creating a new account within an account replaces the current user?

Basic info of the teachers/students are saved in FirebaseDatabase using email as a key.

I'm using the Firebase Assistant in creating the account.

my Code in retrieving userEmail and DatabaseReference

`String currentEmail = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("AccountInfo").child("Teacher").child(EncodeString(currentEmail));`

EncodeString is just a String replace for "." to "DOT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better and more secure way of doing this is to use the Firebase Admin SDK.
You would set a [custom user claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on teachers to differentiate them from students. Then on student creation, send the teacher's ID token and the student's info to a server where you confirm teacher role and then [create the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with Admin SDK.

Otherwise, if you just want to create another account without logging out the teacher, you can explicitly [instantiate a new FirebaseApp instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String)) and use the other non-default instance to create the accounts.

However, from a security point of view, the first suggestion is the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'm still trying to figure out how to use FirebaseAdminSDK and I dont have that much time, so I ended up using your second option and created a new FirebaseOption for my 2nd authentication, and use it to create a new Account then simply log it out after creating the account. What would be its downside?

Comment: The main downside is that you don't restrict student creation to teachers only. If that is not a bid deal to you, then it's fine.